# Loop-Suspension adjunction unit is stable equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups, spectra

Let $X$ be a sequential spectrum, then the unit of the $(\Sigma,\Omega)$-adjunction yields a map $\eta : X \to \Omega \Sigma X$. The authors of the book *Foundations of Stable Homotopy Theory* (p. 48) then claim that $\eta$ is a $\pi_*$-isomorphism because $\pi_*(\eta)$ is part of the colimit sequence defining the homotopy groups of spectra:
$$ \pi_{n+a}(X_a) \to \pi_{n+a}(\Omega \Sigma X_a) \cong \pi_{1+n+a}(\Sigma X_a) \to \pi_{1+n+a}(X_{1+a}).$$ Why does this observation show that $\eta$ is a $\pi_*$-isomorphism? Does this already tell us that the colimit sequence is somehow compatible with the one for $\pi_n(\Omega \Sigma X)$?

(I know a different argument using that suspension and loop space are $\pi_*$-equivalences along with triangle identities but I want to understand this more direct argument.)

Comment: I can now see why $\eta$ is $\pi_*$-split monic (which is probably also what the authors had in mind). But I can't yet see why it's also $\pi_*$-split epic, as it's not clear to me (at least without further computation) whether $\pi_{n+a}(\Omega \Sigma X_a) \to \pi_{1+n+a}(X_{1+a})$ is part of the colimit sequence defining $\pi_n(\Omega \Sigma X)$.

Comment: Turns out my argument that $\eta$ is $\pi_*$-split monic is not what the authors had in mind :p See the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general fact about sequential colimits (or even more generally colimits over posets). $\newcommand\colim{\operatorname{colim}}$

Let $A : \mathbb{N}\to \mathcal{C}$ be some sequential diagram.
$\mathbb{N}$ has an endomorphism $s$ defined by $s(n)=n+1$.
There is a corresponding natural transformation $\sigma : A \to s^*A$,
which at $n$ is the map $f_n : A_n\to A_{n+1}$ which is $A(n\le n+1)$, the transition map in the sequential diagram.

In fact, more generally, let $t : \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ be any nondecreasing map, then $t$ gives an endomorphism of $\mathbb{N}$ as a category, so we can consider the pullback $t^*A$. If $t$ additionally satisfies $t(n)\ge n$ for all $n$, then there is a natural transformation $\tau: A\to t^*A$ which at $n$ is the unique map $A_n\to A_{t(n)}$ in the diagram $A$.

Now if we assume that $t$ is cofinal (for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $t(N)\ge n$), the following is true.

> **Proposition.** $\colim A$ exists if and only if $t^*\colim A$ exists. In this case if $t(n)\ge n$ for all $n$, so $\tau$ exists, then $\tau$ induces a morphism $\tilde{\tau}:\colim A\to \colim t^* A$ on passing to colimits which is an isomorphism.

*Proof*.

It suffices to give a natural isomorphism between $\newcommand\cocone{\operatorname{co-cone}}\cocone_A$ and $\cocone_{t^*A}$, the functors that the colimits represent. Given some cocone to $A$, $(X, i_n: A_n\to X)$, we get a cocone to $t^*A$ by taking $(X, i_{t(n)}: A_{t(n)}\to X)$. However, it turns out that we can also go backwards, since $t$ is cofinal. If we are given $(Y,j_m : A_{t(m)}\to Y)$, we can define
$i_n : A_n\to Y$ by taking $N$ large enough that $t(N)\ge n$, and then defining $i_n$ to be the composite $A_n \to A_{t(N)} \xrightarrow{j_N} Y$. This is well defined regardless of the choice of $N$ because $\mathbb{N}$ is a poset and $(Y,j_m)$ are a cocone to $t^* A$. This gives us a cocone $(Y, i_n)$ to $A$. These operations are inverse to each other, so we have a natural isomorphism as desired.

Finally we need to show that when $t(n)\ge n$ for all $n$, and if $\colim A$ exists then $\tau$ induces an isomorphism on the colimits. First let's fix some notation. Let $i_n : A_n\to \colim A$ be the inclusions for the colimit of $A$, let $j_n : A_{t(n)}\to \colim t^*A$ be the inclusions of the colimit of $t^*A$, and let $\tau_n: A_n\to A_{t(n)}$ be the components of $\tau$.
Then we observe that $\tilde{\tau}$ is defined by
applying the universal property of the colimit $\colim A$ to the cocone
$(\colim t^*A, j_n \circ \tau_n)$. But we know (up to isomorphism) what the $j_n$ are. By the first half of this proof the $j_n$ are $i_{t(n)}$, so
$$j_n\circ \tau_n = i_{t(n)}\circ \tau_n = i_n,$$
since $\tau_n : A_n\to A_{t(n)}$ is a map in the diagram $A$ and $i$ is a
cocone to $A$. Thus after potentially composing with an isomorphism $(\colim t^*A, j_n)\to (\colim A, i_{t(n)})$, $\tilde{\tau}$ is actually given by the colimiting cone itself, so we have that for some isomorphism $\phi$, $\phi\circ \tilde{\tau} = 1_{\colim A}$, and thus $\tilde{\tau}$ is an isomorphism itself (namely $\phi^{-1}$). $\blacksquare$

**Edited to fix the final argument**

Build a modified version of the stable homotopy group colimit sequence as follows.

Fix $a$, let $P_{2n} = \pi_{n+a}(X_a)$, let $P_{2n+1} = \pi_{n+a}(\Omega\Sigma X_a)$, let the maps $f_{2n} : P_{2n}\to P_{2n+1}$ be $\pi_{n+a}(\eta_{X_a})$, and let the maps $f_{2n+1} : P_{2n+1}\to P_{2n+2}$ be given by the composite of $\pi_{1+n+a}$ applied to the structure map $\Sigma X_a\to X_{a+1}$ with the isomorphism $\pi_{n+a}(\Omega\Sigma X_a)\cong \pi_{n+1+a}(\Sigma X_a)$.

Let $d: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ be given by $d(n) =2n$, and let
$\delta  : P\to d^*P$ be the corresponding natural transformation.
Note that $d^*P$ is precisely the sequence that usually defines the stable homotopy groups.

Now consider the $\sigma$ natural transformation, $\sigma_P$, for this sequence. If we restrict to even $n$, then $\sigma_P$ corresponds to $\pi_{\bullet+a}(\eta)$. In other words $d^*\sigma_P = \pi_{\bullet + a}(\eta)$. We have a commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P @>\sigma_P>> s^* P\\
@V\delta VV @V\delta VV \\
d^*P @>>\pi_{\bullet+a}(\eta)> d^*s^*P.\\
\end{CD}
$$
Termwise this commutative diagram is
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P_n @>>> P_{n+1}\\
@VVV @VVV \\
P_{2n}=\pi_{n+a}(X_a) @>>\pi_{n+a}(\eta_{X_a})> P_{2n+1}=\pi_{n+a}(\Omega \Sigma X_a).\\
\end{CD}
$$

Now if we take colimits of this diagram of functors, three of the maps, $\sigma_P$ and both $\delta$s induce isomorphisms on the colimit. Therefore the last map does as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this well-written answer! But is this really the situation we're looking for? The map $\pi_*(\eta)$ only yields $\pi_{n+a}(X_a) \to \pi_{n+a}(\Omega \Sigma X_a)$ after all and not all of the map $\pi_{n+a}(X_a) \to \pi_{1+n+a}(X_{1+a})$ which goes into the colimit system.

Comment: @QiZhu Oh you're right, that was careless of me. Basically the same argument applies, but I'll edit this later to be more careful. Essentially one could subdivide the sequential colimit by spacing $\pi_*(\eta)$ to be the even maps (starting at 0) and use the spectrum structure maps as the odd maps. Then this argument tells us that the colimit is unchanged and then $\pi_*(\eta)$ really is $\sigma$ on the nose. Essentially if $\sigma$ factors naturally then the component natural transformations will also induce natural isomorphisms on the colimits.

Comment: (when I say that it's $\sigma$ on the nose, I mean that it corresponds to $\sigma$ for the double spaced one under the isomorphism once you take colimits)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have to admit that I can't really follow how exactly you are modifying your argument and would appreciate it if you can edit your answer with what you want to do whenever you have time (it's not urgent!).

Comment: @QiZhu Edited to fix the argument.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it helped me a lot! (I've also just written another more concrete answer with your help.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jgon's wonderfully general argument, I understand the idea of it now. So let me write out a concrete argument where one can quickly see the intuition.

We show surjectivity and injectivity.

- Surjectivity: Let $[f:S^{n+a} \to \Omega \Sigma X_a] \in \pi_n(\Omega \Sigma X)$. If we denote by $[\alpha(f)]$ the image of $[f]$ under $\pi_{n+a}(\Omega \Sigma X_a) \cong \pi_{1+n+a}(\Sigma X_a)$, then we obtain $$ [f] = [\eta \circ \sigma_{a} \circ \alpha(f):S^{1+n+a} \to X_{1+a}] \in \operatorname{im}{(\pi_n(\eta))}.$$
- Injectivity: Say $[f], [g] \in \pi_n(X)$ agree after postcomposition with $\eta$. But then, they also agree after going far enough in the colimit system. On the other hand, this is the same thing as $[f] = [g]$.

Or even more succinctly: The map $\pi_n(\eta)$ moves the representative by one slot in the sequential colimit system. But doing this doesn't change the class of the representative.